# Add custom header to Amazon AWS ELB response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I would like to add a custom header to the responses generated by an Elastic Load Balancer. This custom header should contain the EC2 instance ID (something like X-EC2-Instance-ID=123456) corresponding to the backend who has handled the request.

Is it possible to do this from the ELB itself, without configuring this header on each backend server?

thanks!

Comment: by any chance is this now possible with AWS ALB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't possible to accomplish this at the ELB. You would have to add this at the EC2 level.